# maven profile should be activated but is not

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have been using maven for years now but I bumped into an issue.
As always I create a repo to illustrate my issue:
`git clone https://github.com/clembo590/issues.git --branch mavenProfiles`

I just created a multi module maven where I expect the QA profile to be active but it is not.

Here is how the parent pom look like:

```
  <profiles>
    <!-- build mdr-commons ONLY IF PRESENT -->
    <profile>
      <id>mdr-commons</id>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <exists>mdr-commons/pom.xml</exists>
        </file>
      </activation>
      <modules>
        <module>mdr-commons</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>QA</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>

          <!-- this is to check that the coded is formatted : you can use 'apply' instead of 'check' to actually format the code -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

if you run `mvn clean install` you will get
those logs:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mdr-parent                                                         [pom]
[INFO] mdr-commons                                                        [pom]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.example:mdr-parent >-----------------------
[INFO] Building mdr-parent 1.0.0                                          [1/2]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mdr-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ mdr-parent ---
[INFO] Installing ...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.example:mdr-commons >-----------------------
[INFO] Building mdr-commons 1.0.0                                         [2/2]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mdr-commons ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spotless-maven-plugin:2.11.1:check (default) @ mdr-commons ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ mdr-commons ---
[INFO] Installing ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

spotless-maven-plugin is not executed when building mdr-parent which means that QA profile is not active when build mdr-parent. (it is active when building mdr-commons)

**question 1:**
why is QA profile not active when building mdr-parent?

**question 2:**
just delete completely the folder called mdr-commons and re run `mvn clean install`
--> why is QA profile active this time ? (you will see in the logs that the spotless-maven-plugin is executed)

thanks in advance `maven experts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in [Details on profile activation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#details-on-profile-activation) of the Maven Guide.

TLDR; Profiles which are activeByDefault are deactivated whenever another profile was activated by any other method.

The mdr-commons profile is activated if file `mdr-commons/pom.xml` exists. In that case, the QA profile is deactivated. If this file does not exist, the QA profile is "active by default".

Answer (score 1):

That is described in [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

> This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless
> another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the
> previously described methods. All profiles that are active by default
> are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated
> on the command line or through its activation config.